# Operation Contract with Different Source or Action Url

Tags: wcf, action, contract, operation, operationcontract

Our third party API provides two different web services but have identical methods, models.  Nevertheless they only differ on  URIs (Web Service Path, Action Path [Operation Contract].

So I have decided to:

1. Generate the code from their wsdl using VS.
2. Edit the namespacing to use the same and to be "Common" and not use the service reference instead i use the Reference.cs edited code.
3. Create a new proxy that will handle the correct URI of the service to use (wrapped the Reference.cs inside of it).

Now, I having an issue with the "Method1", because they have different Action Name.  Having an exception of:

> "Server did not recognize the value of
>   HTTP Header SOAPAction:
>   http://www.api.com/service/Method1"

I just notice that it the correct action name is: http://www.api.com/service1/Method1

The question now is, is there any configuration or behavior that i can use to correct the action name for each method for each service?

Or as long as they keep on adding contracts for each implementation of the API, i should also keep on adding the contracts for each, and just use the ChannelFactory for this?

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up directly using the `ChannelFactory` when faced with the same problem

In my implementation,  I had a base interface that had all the common methods to the 2 APIs.  Then I had 2 seperate intefaces - one for each 3-rd party API version - that inherits from the base interface and adds methods and `[OperationContract]` attributes that varied between the two implementations.

When instantianting `ChannelFactory<>`  I used one of the child interfaces.    Helped to keep the consumer code clean and maintainable

Comment: Thanks for that, it really clears out that ChannelFactory is the right one for here.  When you say you used one of the child interfaces, does it mean below?

`interface Base`
`interface Api1 : Base`
`interface Api2 : Base`

`ChannelFactory<Base>`
`

Is this correct? I just wonder because i end up using the seperate contracts when creating instance of the ChannelFactor<TChannel>.